# Convert Char array to uint8_t vector

Tags: c++, vector, char, type-conversion

For some project i need to send encoded messages but i can only give vetor of uint8_t to be sent, and i have a char array (with numbers and string i converted to hexadecimal in it) and a pointer on the array.  I encode the msg which is an object into the buffer then i have to send it and decode it etc.

```
char buffer[1024]
char *p = buffer
size_t bufferSize = sizeof(buffer)
Encode(msg,p,bufferSize)

std::vector<uint8_t> encodedmsg; //here i need to put my message in the buffer
Send(encodedmsg.data(),encodedmsg.size()) //Only taking uint8_t vector
```

Here is the prototype of send :

```
uint32_t Send(const uint8_t * buffer, const std::size_t bufferSize)
```

I already looked at some questions but no one have to replace it in a vector or convert to uint8_t.
I thinked bout memcpy or reinterpreted cast or maybe using a for loop but i don't really know how to do it whitout any loss.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your code suggest that `Send()` function takes pointer to `uint8_t`, not `std::vector<uint8_t>`.
And since `char` and `uint8_t` has same memory size you just could do:

```
Send(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(p), bufferSize);
```

But if you want to do everything "right" you could do this:

```
encodedmsg.resize(bufferSize);
std::transform(p, p + bufferSize, encodedmsg.begin(), [](char v) {return static_cast<uint8_t>(v);});
```

Comment: thanks a lot i'll try, actually i did " std::vector<uint8_t> encodedmsg(buffer, buffer + bufferSize / sizeof(char)); " but clearly not working.

Comment: This way i can use v.data() and v.size() in my send function?

Comment: Interesting... `std::vector<uint8_t> encodedmsg(buffer, buffer + bufferSize / sizeof(char));` should also work. Are you sure you need to send entire `bufferSize` data, not some other value reurned by `Encode()` for example? And what does it mean exactly by "not workig"?

Comment: Yes, of course you can use v.data() and v.size() anywhere when you have ready vector.

Comment: First when using your resize transform way i got 3 errors:
error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
expected primary-expression before 'char'

Comment: Secondly, using the encodedmsg(buffer ...) way, it SEEMS to works, when i try to display using boost unit test only the start of the message is right, i got one string then numbers and it display the string correctly but then blank characters (like a lot) and then i got � characters.

Comment: For first solution you probably need to set proper compiler flags, i.e. `--std=c++11` for GCC. For second solution it seems that you need to set correct size, as I wrote earlier, i.e. you need to determine how much bytes you message occupies in buffer and send exactly this number of bytes.

Comment: Actually i am using c++ 98 and i can't changes theses parameters since i compile remotely with a Jenkins job (btw can't move this convo to tchat since IM services are blocked in the company)
For the second solution i actually don't know how to do it.

Comment: Ok. Then drop first solution, since it will give you exactly same result with same problems. You need to find out how `Encode()` function works. Theoretically it should somehow inform you how much bytes in buffer it filled.

Comment: Thanks, for the encodedmsg(buffer ...) way, when i look more closely to the result i think he tries to transform everything to uint8_t so for the data which are actually char it works perfectly (the beginning, address and domain) but then it is followed by ints (size etc) and the conversion is making theses blank characters/strange characters